# Using pandas, how to assign the values in the column based on the values from another colum?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with two columns that looks like this:

```
    Name    Date
Brown   1/5/2021
Brown   12/15/2011
Brown   1/25/2006
Davis   1/9/2021
Davis   3/9/2004
Davis   1/29/2021
Garcia  1/7/2021
Garcia  11/17/2008
Garcia  1/13/2013
Johnson 1/3/2021
Johnson 1/13/2017
Johnson 12/23/2011
Jones   1/6/2021
Jones   1/16/2009
Jones   1/4/2014
Martinez    1/11/2018
Martinez    1/21/2002
Martinez    1/31/2021
Miller  1/8/2021
Miller  2/18/2021
Miller  1/28/2021
Rodriguez   1/10/2020
Rodriguez   1/20/2001
Rodriguez   1/30/2021
Smith   1/2/2021
Smith   1/12/2021
Smith   5/22/2010
Williams    1/4/2021
Williams    1/24/2016
Williams    1/4/2006
```

I am trying to add new column and enter the value in that column based on value from the first column. So for every instance of:

```
    Smith in column Name, the new column Grade will have letter A, 
Johnson will have B
Williams will have C
Brown will have D
Jones will have E
Garcia will have    F
Miller will have    G
Davis will have H
Rodriguez will have K
Martinez will have  L
```

So desired output would look like this:

```
    Name    Date    Grade
Brown   1/5/2021    D
Brown   12/15/2011  D
Brown   1/25/2006   D
Davis   1/9/2021    H
Davis   3/9/2004    H
Davis   1/29/2021   H
Garcia  1/7/2021    F
Garcia  11/17/2008  F
Garcia  1/13/2013   F
Johnson 1/3/2021    B
Johnson 1/13/2017   B
Johnson 12/23/2011  B
Jones   1/6/2021    E
Jones   1/16/2009   E
Jones   1/4/2014    E
Martinez    1/11/2018   L
Martinez    1/21/2002   L
Martinez    1/31/2021   L
Miller  1/8/2021    G
Miller  2/18/2021   G
Miller  1/28/2021   G
Rodriguez   1/10/2020   K
Rodriguez   1/20/2001   K
Rodriguez   1/30/2021   K
Smith   1/2/2021    A
Smith   1/12/2021   A
Smith   5/22/2010   A
Williams    1/4/2021    C
Williams    1/24/2016   C
Williams    1/4/2006    C
```

What I tried so far works for single instance like:

```
df['Grade']= df['Name'].apply(lambda x: 'D' if (x == 'Brown'))
```

Instead of 10 lambda functions, is there a more elegant way that I could do within one function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as elegant, but it's another solution.

```
df['Grade']= df['Name'].map({'Brown': 'D' , ....})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.select` from `numpy` (usually stylized as `np`):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Brown', 1: 'Brown', 2: 'Brown', 3: 'Davis', 4: 'Davis', 5: 'Davis', 6: 'Garcia', 7: 'Garcia', 8: 'Garcia', 9: 'Johnson', 10: 'Johnson', 11: 'Johnson', 12: 'Jones', 13: 'Jones', 14: 'Jones', 15: 'Martinez', 16: 'Martinez', 17: 'Martinez', 18: 'Miller', 19: 'Miller', 20: 'Miller', 21: 'Rodriguez', 22: 'Rodriguez', 23: 'Rodriguez', 24: 'Smith', 25: 'Smith', 26: 'Smith', 27: 'Williams', 28: 'Williams', 29: 'Williams'}, 
                   'Date': {0: '1/5/2021', 1: '12/15/2011', 2: '1/25/2006', 3: '1/9/2021', 4: '3/9/2004', 5: '1/29/2021', 6: '1/7/2021', 7: '11/17/2008', 8: '1/13/2013', 9: '1/3/2021', 10: '1/13/2017', 11: '12/23/2011', 12: '1/6/2021', 13: '1/16/2009', 14: '1/4/2014', 15: '1/11/2018', 16: '1/21/2002', 17: '1/31/2021', 18: '1/8/2021', 19: '2/18/2021', 20: '1/28/2021', 21: '1/10/2020', 22: '1/20/2001', 23: '1/30/2021', 24: '1/2/2021', 25: '1/12/2021', 26: '5/22/2010', 27: '1/4/2021', 28: '1/24/2016', 29: '1/4/2006'}})

conds = [df['Name'].eq('Smith'),
        df['Name'].eq('Johnson'),
        df['Name'].eq('Williams'),
        df['Name'].eq('Brown'),
        df['Name'].eq('Jones'),
        df['Name'].eq('Garcia'),
        df['Name'].eq('Miller'),
        df['Name'].eq('Davis'),
        df['Name'].eq('Rodriguez'),
        df['Name'].eq('Martinez')]
choices = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','K','L']
df['Grade'] = np.select(conds, choices, np.nan)
```

```
         Name        Date Grade
0       Brown    1/5/2021     D
1       Brown  12/15/2011     D
2       Brown   1/25/2006     D
3       Davis    1/9/2021     H
4       Davis    3/9/2004     H
5       Davis   1/29/2021     H
6      Garcia    1/7/2021     F
7      Garcia  11/17/2008     F
8      Garcia   1/13/2013     F
9     Johnson    1/3/2021     B
10    Johnson   1/13/2017     B
11    Johnson  12/23/2011     B
12      Jones    1/6/2021     E
13      Jones   1/16/2009     E
14      Jones    1/4/2014     E
15   Martinez   1/11/2018     L
16   Martinez   1/21/2002     L
17   Martinez   1/31/2021     L
18     Miller    1/8/2021     G
19     Miller   2/18/2021     G
20     Miller   1/28/2021     G
21  Rodriguez   1/10/2020     K
22  Rodriguez   1/20/2001     K
23  Rodriguez   1/30/2021     K
24      Smith    1/2/2021     A
25      Smith   1/12/2021     A
26      Smith   5/22/2010     A
27   Williams    1/4/2021     C
28   Williams   1/24/2016     C
29   Williams    1/4/2006     C
```